# Use and modify data from SAP HANA in Power Apps

Tags: hana, powerapps, power-platform

My requirement is to retrieve data from a SAP HANA-database and use it inside a Microsoft Power App (ex. in a gallery). The App should also have the ability to modify and write back the data. The solution shouldn't use any software which isn't from Microsoft or SAP if somehow possible.

My current idea is to use a Power Platform-Dataflow to retrieve data from a SAP HANA source and to create an entity in Common Data Service out of it. This entity can then be used in a Power App. However, as far as I know, it isn't possible to write data back to SAP HANA this way as the modified data will only be updated in CDS.

Are there any ways to tackle the problem properly?

Comment: It does not related to SAP HANA, because if Dataflow supports RDBMS as data target, then you can do this, if not then you cannot. But looks like it does not. HANA exposes ODBC and JDBC drivers, so your software is free to use them and move data from and to database if your HANA licence allows it.

Comment: ODBC doesn't seem to be an option as a connection for Power Apps, right. However, one thing I could come up with is creating an OData-service that exposes the required data from HANA. I would then call the service via a custom connector in Power Apps. As I don't have all the resources to implement this yet, I would like to ask in advance if this is a feasible solution.